# Convert the list in text file to dictionary on Python

Tags: python

Convert following list into python dictionary:

```
[["A", ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"], ["B", ["eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh"]]]
```

Expected:

```
{'A': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'], 'B': ['eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh']}
```

if possible to pandas or koalas dataframe?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: `{x[0]: x[1] for x in mylist}` should do the job. Why bother with pandas?

Comment: @Arjun Sharma please accept the answer if it works for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The list in your code is a syntax error. It is missing a parenthesis:

```
[
    ["A", ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]^missing here,
    ["B", ["eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh"]],
]
```

If you add the missing bracket you can simply do:

```
import pandas as pd

ls =  [
    ["A", ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]],
    ["B", ["eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh"]],
] 

df = pd.DataFrame(
   dict(ls)
)
```

Running dict over a list of two element lists is equivalent to the code proposed in the comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought:

```py
final_dict = {}
for elem in list_name:
   final_dict[elem[0]] = elem[1:]
```

Making use of list splicing can greatly reduce the number of lines of code and make the solution more elegant.

Happy coding!

Comment: Please check your output and compare with requirement you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719823/14867730 by @GuillemB